# Injecting RSA key to putty

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I want to ssh to a remote machine with a `rsa` key. In linux, it is simple:

```
ssh -i file.rsa username@remote.com
```

But how can I do that in windows using `putty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `puttygen` utility can import your RSA key and save it in the PuTTY format. To use the key in PuTTY, you can specify your private key file in the "Auth" subnode of the "SSH" node of the connection dialog or use the `-i` argument to specify your private key file.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your key settings in putty. Look for the Connection->SSH->Auth menu on the left side of the window.